# Alternatives to storing data to database rather then using Parse

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have been using Parse lately for applications I develop, mainly due to the simplicity of getting an app off the ground. This could eventually be costly, more so unless I store to my own database on a rented server, I'd assume. So my question is: How would I go about storing data externally to my own server? Is there any sort of framework like parse for this with option to use one's own server storage instead? I'd assume theres something considering writing a whole login system etc that's secure multiple times would seem a bit repetitive, hence Parse. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Google has provided a mobile backend starter some time ago, here is the link https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/. Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have. Kindly look into [DynamoDB](https://console.aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/home?#) from amazon.
[Here](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/SDKs/iOS) is a good documentation for iOS SDK.

More granular detail is [here](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/SDKs/iOS/8829919029640036)

I hope that helps.

***You may need to have an account with amazon aws in order to create your appID & all.***